# Not capitalized titles in headers

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, capitalization

I am trying to write a document using the `book` class. I would like to have empty footers I also would like to have, on the header of each page, right-aligned, the chapter title (not capitalized) followed by a space and then the page number (yes, that includes the first pages of chapters). And I also want to add the unnumbered chapters to the table of contents. Please take a look at this MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\title{A title}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize{\leftmark}\quad{\footnotesize{\thepage}}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\cleardoublepage\@startsection
  {chapter}
  {0}
  {-\parindent}
  {\baselineskip}
  {\baselineskip}
  {\normalfont\Huge\textbf}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introdução}
\lipsum[1-5]
\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{Start}
\lipsum[6-15]
\chapter{New chapter}
\end{document}
```

This almost achieves what I want. It *does* achieve what I want in the `\mainmatter`. The problem lies in the`\frontmatter`. As you can see if you compile it, the headers of the first four pages are “CONTENTS  i”, “CONTENTS  ii”, “CONTENTS  iii”, and “CONTENTS  iv”, whereas I am aiming at having “Contents  i”, “Contents  ii”, “Introduction  i”, and “Introduction  ii”. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this one:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
%\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{A chapter}
    \section{Start}
    \lipsum[6-15]
    \chapter{New chapter}
    \chapter{A chapter}
    \section{Start}
    \lipsum[6-15]
    \chapter{New chapter}
    \chapter{A chapter}
    \section{Start}
    \lipsum[6-15]
    \chapter{New chapter}
    \chapter{A chapter}
    \section{Start}
    \lipsum[6-15]
    \chapter{New chapter}
    \chapter{A chapter}
    \section{Start}
    \lipsum[6-15]
    \chapter{New chapter}
    \chapter{A chapter}
    \section{Start}
    \lipsum[6-15]
    \chapter{New chapter}
    \chapter{A chapter}
    \section{Start}
    \lipsum[6-15]
    \chapter{New chapter}
    \chapter{A chapter}
    \section{Start}
    \lipsum[6-15]
    \chapter{New chapter}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT**: If You want page number like in Your question edit the corresponding lines this way:

```
%\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\rightmark} \;\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries \thepage \;\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
```